# How to use cowin api to get the states of the country?

Tags: api

I want to use cowin api to get the states of the country .
The docs of the cowin api is given here  https://apisetu.gov.in/api/cowin#/

Comment: Which programming language do you plan to use? It is a description of a REST API that you even can use to test out the stuff directly on the webpage, but probably that's not what you want, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the documentation given in the website https://apisetu.gov.in/api/cowin#/

You can get the states as JSON by calling the link below

https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states

Comment: It's not _that_ easy, you will have to provide some form of authentication. Did you even try it out with the Swagger tool?

Comment: what i understood from the question is , i think the user wanted to test out stuff directly from a webpage